# How to import python module or package in a Tree Structure Repo

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

I have a project with several python files. But when I try to structure the file into different packages, I got some problems.

So the structure I want to make structure be like

```
Repo
|
+--Package1
|  +-- __init__.py
|  +-- code1.py
|  +-- code2.py (using class in code1.py)
+--Package2
|  +-- __init__.py
|  +-- code3.py (using class in code 2 and code 4)
|  +-- cdoe4.py
+ __init__.py
+ main.py (using function in code 3)
+ utils.py
```

All codes from `code1.py` to `code4.py` used the functions in `utils.py`.

But when I do `from Package.code3 import Someclass`. Because in `code3.py`, it imports codes in `code2.py` and `code4.py`. So I always get `module code2 not found error`.

I tried putting the following code in `Package1/__init__.py`

```
from Package1 import code1
from Package1 import code2
```

And similarly, putting the following code in `Package2/__init__.py`

```
from Package2 import code3
from Package2 import code4
```

But I still get the error.
What can I do to import such structured files?

---

It seems adding `sys.path.append('./Package')` solved the problem. But I wonder why I need to add this line since I already imported package1.

I really appreciate it if you can answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same error. Resetting the python-path solved it for me.

```
set PYTHONPATH=.
```

Comment: What python-path is that? Do you mean to reset the system environment?

Comment: It seems adding `sys.path.append('./Package')` solved the problem. But I wonder why I need to add this line, since we already imported package1.